# How to pass array as parameter for stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, dapper

I have a function like

```
SELECT * from "transaction".stp_txn_gettxndetails(0,0,3,cast('2005-03-01' as date),cast('2023-03-28' as date),ARRAY[10063],0,0,0,'0',0);
```

but I am unable to pass `ARRAY[10063]` as a parameter.

```cs
public long[] p_transactionids { get; set; } 
parameters.Add("p_transactionids", entity.p_transactionids, DbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

This is how I pass the value as a parameter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Dapper documentation](https://www.learndapper.com/parameters), you should utilize the Dapper's anonymous type parameter.

```cs
var parameters = new 
{ 
    p_transactionids = entity.p_transactionids
};
```

---

Another approach is constructing a dictionary of `Dictionary<string, object>` type according to this [article](https://makolyte.com/csharp-adding-dynamic-query-parameters-with-dapper/).

```cs
var dictParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    ["p_transactionids"] = entity.p_transactionids
};

var parameters = new DynamicParameters(dictParameters);

// Add other params. Example:
// dynamicParameters.AddDynamicParams(new { name = "The Matrix" });
```